# SPO Document Library (Maximum Number of Documents)?

Tags: document-library

I am looking for some clarity on how many documents I can put into a document library in SharePoint Online (2013) in O365.  In one scenario, we have 60,000+ reports that we need to upload.  They are all the same type of document and it is my intent to put them into the same document library.

The way I currently understand it, I can upload up to 30,000,000 items into a list/library, but the "views" will only return 5000.  Which I believe would be fine, as we would be using metadata and filters to narrow down the views.

Am I off the mark here?  Or are there other pitfalls I should be aware of with large scale doc management in SharePoint online O365 (like using unique permissions).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say properly plan your list for that much items, even MSFT support it but cause the issue. I think you are on track if you use you must configure metadata-based navigation...as MSFt mentioned in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2759051).

in the TechNet article [Software Boundaries and Limits for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary). In this linked article, only the sections on List and Library Limits, Page Limits, and Security Limits apply to SharePoint Online